# Fatal Error: how to resolve a member function prepare?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert values into a MySQL database called 'todo' I made a PDO connection.

```
    <?php

 include_once('class.database.php');
 class ManageUsers{
     public $link;
     function __construct(){
         $db_connection = new dbConnection();
         $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
         return $this->link;
     }
     function registerUsers($username,$password,$ip_address,$time,$date){
         $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,password,ip_address,time,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
         $values = array($username,$password,$ip_address,$time,$date);
         $query->execute($values);
         $counts = $query->rowCount();
         return $counts;
     }
 }
    $users = new ManageUsers();
    echo $users->registerUsers('bob','bob','127.0.0.1','12:00','29-02-2012');
?>

<?php

    class dbConnection{
            protected $db_conn;
            public $db_name = 'todo';
            public $db_user = 'root';
            public $db_pass = 'password';
            public $db_host = 'localhost';
            function connect(){
                try{
                    $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
                    return $this->db_conn;
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    return $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

The result should be 1 - i.e. it should add one row into the database. Instead, I get the following error message.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\class.ManageUsers.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\class.ManageUsers.php(24): ManageUsers->registerUsers('bob', 'bob', '127.0.0.1', '12:00', '29-02-2012') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\class.ManageUsers.php on line 15

What have I done wrong?

Comment: It's failing because your $link isn't working it looks like

Comment: Why do you have a `return` in the constructor?

Comment: Since you're not checking what your `connect()` method actually returns (resource on success and a string if an exception occures), I would recommend not having that try/catch at all. If you're database connection doesn't work, there's usually no need to continue with the script anyway, at least if you need the DB for it to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should not return the `$this->link` in your `ManageUsers::__construct`. construct will by default return a new object of the class. Your error says,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in
```

That means your `$link` property contains a string instead of a db object. Which makes sense because of the following portion of your code: (in `dbConnection` class)

```
catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
```

once your database connection fails you are returning the error message using `$e->getMessage()` which returns a string.

In general if db connection fails you should terminate the script. If you change the script to something like:

```
catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
```

You will know why your db connection is failing

Comment: It says that it could not find the driver. I have already uncommented the line in php.ini, Do you know why?

Comment: did you restart your apache after you changed php.ini?

Comment: Can I do that by simply hitting 'stop' and then 'start' in the xampp control panel? Because if so, yes, I have done that; it still says it cannot find the driver

Comment: yes that should work. check your phpinfo(). You should be able to see it from your xampp homepage. (or simply run echo phpinfo()). See if you can find `pdo_mysql` installed in there?

Comment: It could not find that; what I did find is that PDO support is sqlite - is this the problem? Do I not have support for PDO?

Comment: Right, since you are using mysql, you do need pdo_mysql driver installed. Once you did that, you would see PDO support for both sqlite and mysql